# jquery issue calling on a class for a hover over plug in

Tags: jquery, html, css

This script is supposed to have text move up from below the image when the users mouse hovers over the image. I do not believe that the jQuery is calling on the class properly and that is why it is not working. I have included code from the jquery plugin as well as the section of html that is supposed to work with this plug in. If you have any questions for me please do not hesitate to ask I will be waiting for a response, I just started using jQuery today and am enjoying it when things work, but have been searching for an answer for some time now and am just baffled with why I can not figure this out.

```
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>

  $(function(){
  $(' #d1').contenthover({
   overlay_width:300,
   overlay_height:150,
   effect:'slide',
   slide_direction:'bottom',
   overlay_x_position:'center',
   overlay_y_position:'bottom',
   overlay_background:'#000',
   overlay_opacity:0.8
   });
   });

  </script>
```

---

```
  <section id="s-explore">

   <div class="pagebreak"><span>The Lifestyle</span> <i class="down">&lt;</i></div>

    <div class="wrapper layout">

    <div class="col">
        <div class="media">
            <img id="d1" src="images/main.png" />
                <div class="contenthover">
                    <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor</h3>
                    <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames</p>
                    <p><a href="#" class="mybutton">Lorem ipsum</a></p>
                </div>
        </div>

        <div class="body">
            <h1>Vestibulum</h1>
            <h2>quis<br />Vestibulum</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
```

---

Working code:

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML>
 <html>
 <head>

 <link href="hover-content-style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <script>

  $(function(){


   $('#d1').contenthover({
    overlay_width:300,
    overlay_height:150,
    effect:'slide',
    slide_direction:'bottom',
    overlay_x_position:'center',
    overlay_y_position:'bottom',
    overlay_background:'#000',
    overlay_opacity:0.8
    });

    });

    </script>

    <title>JQuery slide on top of image - animation</title>

    </head>

    <body>
      <img id="d1" src="images/vito_red.png" width="318" height="269" />
         <div class="contenthover">
           <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor</h3>
           <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum pulvinar ante quis augue lobortis volutpat. </p>
           <p><a href="#" class="mybutton">Lorem ipsum</a></p>
          </div>

      <script src="hoverslide.js"></script>

      </body>
```

Comment: I am not sure what your question is asking?! Sorry like I said new to jQuery

Comment: There was a question just a little bit ago asking why I would not just use hover(); .... anyone have any thoughts on this?

Comment: ok i didnt know about this contenthover plugin so i am assuming you are trying to use that http://www.backslash.gr/demos/contenthover-jquery-plugin/ so i deleted my comment

Comment: did you actually add the js to your website http://www.backslash.gr/demos/contenthover-jquery-plugin/jquery.contenthover.min.js

Comment: The jquery file itself? no I did not but the plug in works when used not nested in <div> tags like I have it, I will post the working script that I used to test before I added it to the site that I am working on.

Comment: you need to include the js file. i am not exactly sure what you are trying to do. but this is doing something. http://jsfiddle.net/btevfik/MbLNN/

Comment: There I have added the code that works that I tested the plug in on before attempting to add it to the existing site.

Comment: i updated the jsfiddle. look again. i think it works fine.

Comment: WOW you are right I did not add the jQuery file that I added the last time that I tested the code. Thank you so much for helping me with such a idiotic issue..... I am sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: ok i am going to add it as answer. if you can choose it, it would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to include the `js` file : http://www.backslash.gr/demos/contenthover-jquery-plugin/jquery.contenthover.min.js

here is a working example; http://jsfiddle.net/btevfik/MbLNN/

Comment: I would have voted you up but unfortunately I am unable to until I have a 15 rep :(

Comment: that's fine. glad i could help